# How to disable formatting in TextEdit on Mac Yosemite

Tags: macos, textedit, osx-yosemite

When I copy something and paste it from buffer in TextEdit, it saves text formatting (font-color, background-color, font-style) How can I turn that off?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you will be able to turn it off. But you can tweak it in the copy/paste process.

Take a look at this article [here](http://osxdaily.com/2013/04/18/strip-styling-font-formatting-text-mac-os-x/) as it explains how you can copy/paste using a certain combination of keys to skip formatting.

> Paste the copied text and match current style by using Command+Option+Shift+V.
>   Notice the difference from the normal Command+V paste trick, which would include the formatting.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to save text with formatting, you should work with plain text format: menu `Format > Make Plain Text` (⇧⌘T). You can also set plain text format as your default document format in TextEdit `Preferences`.

[image: Text Edit Preferences]